# “Son nom” vs “sa nom” for a female

Tags: pronoms, genre, possessif

I am going through an exercise in a book, which states:

> Elle s'appelle Evelyne Deschamps. __ prénom est Évelyne. __ nom est Deschamps.

The blanks have to be filled with *Sa* or *Son*. Is do not understand how this works.

Should the pronouns correspond to the gender of the words *nom* and *prénon* (and, hence the right answer is *Son*) or should they correspond to the gender of the subject (and hence the right answer is *sa*)?

Comment: The possessive adjective agrees with the gender of the noun, not with the gender of the possessor. See this [web page](http://www.thefrenchexperiment.com/learn-french/possessive-adjectives.php) for a detailed lesson on how possessive adjectives work in French.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy see the word after the possessive adjective or blank in your case  and if it's feminine singular then sa for masculine singular son and for plural it's ses.

Comment: I meant sa for feminine singular and see the word after blank in your case

Comment: Thanks. This clearly answers my questions.

Comment: You could improve your answer a bit by [editing in](https://french.stackexchange.com/posts/44771/edit) what you wrote in the comment.

Answer (score 7):

The right answer is indeed "son" because we say "un nom" and "un prénom" no matter if they are used to speak about a male or a female. Sa (fem.) son (masc.) and ses (plu.) are called in french "Adjectif possesifs".

If in english we say :

> "She walks *her* dog"

in french we will say :

> "Elle promène *son* chien"

if the dog (chien) is a male or

> "Elle promène sa chienne"

if the dog is a female.